# Search on selected area by draw polygons in google map v3

Tags: mysql, database, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to extract min, max latitude and longitude for searching in database with drawing a spacial area in google map with poly, rectangle, circle?
I use this to draw in map via users:

```
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager (
{
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControlOptions:
    {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
        drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE]
    },
    polygonOptions: polyOptions,
    rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
    circleOptions: polyOptions,
    map: map
});
```

So, I want to query to database for fetch the information is exist in selected area.
option for drawing is:
1- google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
2- google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
3- google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE

any can help to me?

Answer (score 2):

Number 2 first.Rectangle Use Bounding box $minLat,$maxLat,$minLng,$minLat

```
$sql ="SELCT * FROM tablename WHERE(lat  BETWEEN ? AND ? )AND (lng  BETWEEN ? AND ?)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    // Assign parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$minLat);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$maxLat);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$minLng);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$maxLng);
```

Number 1 Polygon Use Bounding box of rectangle then javascript pointInPolygon() to eliminate points ouside polygon.

```
function pointInPolygon(polySides,polyX,polyY,x,y) {
 var j = polySides-1 ;
  oddNodes = 0;
  for (i=0; i<polySides; i++) {
    if (polyY[i]<y && polyY[j]>=y  ||  polyY[j]<y && polyY[i]>=y) {
        if (polyX[i]+(y-polyY[i])/(polyY[j]-polyY[i])*(polyX[j]-polyX[i])<x)  {
            oddNodes=!oddNodes; 
        }
    }
   j=i; }

  return oddNodes;
}
```

Number 3 Circle

```
$sql ="SELECT  *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians($) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM tablename HAVING radius < 2 ORDER BY distance "(;
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    // Assign parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$center_lat);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$center_lng);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$center_lat);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$radius);
```